# Google Docs API: Export document as HTML

Tags: python, html, rest, google-api, google-docs-api

I can export a Google Document through this URL, and then getting its content:

`https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=DOC_ID&exportFormat=html`

But the problem is that there's no way of telling when a page starts or ends. The HTML does not wrap each page in its own `div`, not does each element's class describe their page number.

What I'm trying to do is just extract the text and images from a Google Document, while knowing what page the text and images are on. I don't really care about anything else.

Comment: That's not possible, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692673/export-a-specific-page-of-a-google-doc-to-pdf-via-google-apps-script).